# How to get values from sheet correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

im getting an error from this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ();
  var v1 = ss.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = ss.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = ss.getRange(1, v1, v2).getValues()
  Logger.log(data);
```

Exception: The parameters (String,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

P.S. I want to create autofilling calendar, if you have any tips, links or anything that will help, please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

[Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) does not have a method `getRange` that accepts 3 integers as parameters.

The only existing `getRange` method for this class is [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation), which accepts a string instead.

#### Solution:

If you want to retrieve all values from a specific sheet, I'd suggest the following:

- Get the desired sheet you want to retrieve. You could use [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)) for this (or [Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveSheet()) if the script is bound to your spreadsheet and you want to fetch the active sheet, in which case you could have used [SpreadsheetApp.getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActive())).
- Use [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) or, alternatively [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

#### Code snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEET_NAME"); // Change to your actual sheet name
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  /* ALTERNATIVELY:
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn).getValues();
  */
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

Comment: @lamblichus im so confused, i use getSheetByName but for some reason when i use last row or column it say that it cant read null

Comment: @DragonHunter Just to clarify, the spreadsheet is the name of the file, containing several sheets ("tabs"). In this case, `YOUR_SHEET_NAME` would be the name of one of your "tabs". Is that the case? Based on what you said, chances are you don't have one sheet ("tab") with this name.

Comment: @lamblichus, thanks, basicaly what i understand i need to write name of a page from the tab in the buttom of the window, but sadly, same error "Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange."

Comment: @DragonHunter If you got this error you are mixing the two methods I mentioned and not using the code I provided. `getDataRange` does not accept any parameter, as you can see in the documentation I referenced. Consider using the code I provided.

Comment: @lamblichus ,sorry, missed that, you are correct, getRange is correct way to do it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValue());
}
```

Comment: i want use last row and column for cycle later, and sorry, for not sharing url of my sheed but i thing that it will be ok to change getActive to openByUrl